# Copy data from temp table to database table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have copy data from excel to datatable and from that datatable I have created one temp table in sql. I want to insert a data from temp table to database table without using cursor in sql.

Comment: Is this using vb.net and mssql? Can we see your code so far?

Comment: How to you want to insert data by using query or from frontend? Please eloaborate. Also you need to provide both temp table, and db table structures.

Comment: already you have exported from Excel file to Database and again you are saying from temptable to Database table.then where you got struck ??

Comment: @Dipak - why to load in temp table and then to database table, why not directly load the data from datatable to the destination database table?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you created some temp table from data that is provided in excel sheet form. It is already in database. 
Now you want to copy data form one table (temp table) to the second one?
If you want to do it just use

```
SELECT [columns] INTO [destination_table] FROM [source_table]
```